# Conjugacy Class Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't follow the answer to b). I understand the first couple of sentences, as they involve a lemma from the notes but i am lost thereafter.

```
Let G be group.

(a) We say that elements x,y∈G are conjugate (or more precisely are conjugate in G) if there exists g∈G with g−1xg=y. Prove that conjugacy is an equivalence relation.

(b) There equivalence classes in (a) are called conjugacy classes. Prove that a subgroup H of G is normal iff it is a union of conjugacy classes.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the coniugacy classes are the equivalence classes of the relation $$ y \sim x \Longleftrightarrow y = g^{-1}xg$$ with $ g \in G $ and . So if $x \in H $ and $H$ is union of coniugacy classes , then $ y \in [x]_{\sim} \subseteq H$ and so $ y \in H $

Comment: Why does y∈H prove what i am trying to show?

Comment: Because $ g^{-1}xg \in H \ \forall x \in H \Rightarrow \ g^{-1}Hg \subseteq H $